# Can't stop and uninstall Deep Freeze

Tags: windows-xp, deep-freeze

I am trying to uninstall Deep Freeze 2000 in Windows XP, but I can't!

I can't even open the Deep Freeze window because it stops responding! I can't get into Safe mode with Windows XP when I press F8 while booting. It opens a menu to choose with which device to boot the PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to uninstall deep freeze is to first thaw the workstation and then run the original installation package.  Anything else you do will result in your changes being reverted, just like any other changes. If you're having trouble viewing the window on the workstation itself, try thawing from the management console.

If something is broken with your deep freeze installation (I've never seen this), the only thing you could do is re-install the operating system from original media (not located on the frozen volume).

Comment: Is there any other way to start the PC in safe mode, because it doesnt work with F8?

Comment: It sounds like you're hitting F8 too soon, and trigger something in bios. Deepfreeze drivers still load in safe mode, so booting to safemode still won't let you uninstall (thought you might at least be able to get it to let you thaw the machine)

Answer (score 0):

Pull the hard drive out (or boot from a CD), then navigate to the Deepfreeze program folder, and rename the executable from .exe to .old. Reboot, and it won't start up. Then you should be able to uninstall it

Comment: Thank you for your help Luke but I didnt really understand your advice, how is it going to work without hard drive? and I tried to rename them from exe to old but it doesnt work

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: Because DeepFreeze only works when it's running. Pulling out the hard drive, OR booting your computer from a CD, will prevent DF from running and protecting itself